Replace multiple characters in Azure pipeline parameters
We have a condition in our template to replace "parameter.reponame" if it has a "-" to an underscore "_" .
Is there any way in which I can also replace "." to an underscore "_" if it exists in a repo name.
Template :
 - ${{ each environment in parameters.environmentList }}:
  - job: checkmarxScan_${{ replace(environment.repoName, '-', '_') }}
    workspace:
      clean: all  
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell : #Code#


Main Pipeline : Where the parameters are given
name: $(BuildID)

trigger: none

pool: Azure pipelines
jobs:
- template: checkmarx-scan.yml
  parameters:
    environmentList: 
    - repoName: Repo.name, repo-name
      branch: develop
      scaExclusion:
      sastFolderExclusion:
      sastFileExclusion:
      emailId: 


If you have to replace multiple characters you can use replace function multiple times:
replace(replace(environment.repoName, '-', '_'), '.', '_')

It's not pretty, but it works.

Hey Rui, thanks this will work for now. :)
